# Tried drawing a circle using SVG which works for Firefox from a proof of concept but doesn't work in actual project

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This is the HTML and JS that I have used for both proof of concept (POC) and my actual project. This works fine in Firefox for POC but not in the actual project. I just see a square element on inspecting.

```html
<div class="percent-container">
    <div class="percent-text">90%</div>
    <svg class="progress-ring" width="100%" height="100%">
        <circle class="fake-ring" stroke="#008D00" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" r="43%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
        <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" r="43%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

```js
function setProgress(circleClass, percent) {
            var circle = document.getElementsByClassName(circleClass);
            var radius = 22;
            var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
            circle[0].style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
            circle[0].style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;
            const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
            circle[0].style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}
setProgress("fake-ring",100);
setProgress("progress-ring__circle",70);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Also what do you mean it works in "Proof of concept"(?) but not in the project? What are the differences in environment between those two cases?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `viewBox` attribute to your `<svg>` element?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `getElementsByClassName()` into `querySelector()`. Then circle is not an array, but actually the element that you need.

For me it looks like it is working, but I really have no idea what it is that you will achieve with the two circles on top of each other and the styling of that dacharray.

Also the size was a bit off. I added the viewBox attribute to `<svg>` and gave it a width, so that it fits in this snippet view.

```js
function setProgress(circleClass, percent) {
  var circle = document.querySelector(`.${circleClass}`);
  var radius = 22;
  var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

setProgress("fake-ring",100);
setProgress("progress-ring__circle",70);
```

```html
<div class="percent-container">
  <div class="percent-text">90%</div>
  <svg class="progress-ring" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px">
        <circle class="fake-ring" stroke="#008D00" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" r="43%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
        <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" r="43%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```